# SharedPreference long not translating to a String when using .valueOf()

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am not sure why but for some strange reason this long is not converting to a string to be used to programatically fire off a message to the desired .valueOf(constants.myNumber)

Here is the code I am using:

```
shortMessageManager.sendTextMessage(String.valueOf(constants.myNumber), null, "Hey there Tom its Bob from the office down the hall.", null, null);
```

Here is the code used to save the number - Set with in an onClickListener:

```
String num1String = num1.getText().toString();
Long longNum1 = Long.parseLong(num1String);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
prefs.edit().putLong(constants.myNumber, longNum1).commit();
```

here is the code I am trying to pull from:

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class constants {
public static String PREF_NAME = "sharedString";
public static String myNumber = "myNumber";
SharedPreferences prefs;
```

}

- I get the feeling I am missing something silly in here and maybe a second set of eyes looking at it can help. Any ideas?

Comment: "this long is not converting to a string" -- what does this mean?

Comment: show your long number and how you are trying to get it from SharedPreference

Comment: Looks like you're trying to store a phone number in a `long`, which is a bad idea.

Comment: @CommonsWare I mean I am trying to take a long I have saved and make it the value of the string needed to send said text. 

Tom: what would the better number format be for this - Also thanks for enlightening me on that?

Rod: The long number in question is my personal cell phone number so 9 digits.

Comment: But what do you mean by "is not converting"? Focus on clearly and completely explaining your symptoms. Moreover, since the value starts as a string, and ends as a string, and since phone numbers do not have to be all numeric, why are you using a `long` in the first place?

Comment: @CommonsWare Lemme put on my smart hat real quick. - Alright so what I am trying to do is take a phone number I manually input and save to a variable and use it to send a text message. When I do it fails to actually send even though a toast comes up saying it did. I am trying to place that variable into the shortMessageManager method. Well I just tested it with out the valueOf() and it says it sent but I have yet to get anything out of it. - Maybe the better question is "What is the best way to send a text message using a shared preference variable?"

Comment: I'd start by dumping the `long` conversion.

Comment: @CommonsWare I took that out and it still not sending the text. Is there a better way for me to save the information from the editText to the variable to then be used?

Comment: I'd next just hard-code a phone number in your `sendTextMessage()` and see if that works at all.

Comment: It does, that was how I was working on it before. Really what I am doing is much bigger than what you see here. Of course that is rather obvious.